# How do I design web sites with div's and span's (rather than table tags)

Tags: css, layout, html

I'm new to the world of web site designing!

I want to lay out my entire web site with the help of `<div>` & `<span>` rather than `<table>` tags.

Can you recommend any good documentation which will help me in designing this?

thanks.

Comment: Please format your question again. I think there are some missing characters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the tutorials below will help you.
Try to do this layout in css without tables.

Summary intro: http://www.htmlite.com/SD008.php

Medium Level (but more detailed Intro) http://www.hotdesign.com/seybold/everything.html

Lots of great detail: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/04/08/from-table-hell-to-div-hell/

Advanced - believe it or not there are also now (sit down here) - actual css tables!!! **new**
http://www.sitepoint.com/table-based-layout-is-the-next-big-thing/

As Strelok points out though, HTML tables still have a place for now, just save them for real 'table' data - examples: bus schedule, transaction detail, list of users, etc.

The [float tutorial](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/floatutorial/) reference given by Raffael is also excellent reading for learning this area.  Thanks Raffael!

The link that Johannes provided on Best Practices should also be required reading for all web developers!
http://www.iraqtimeline.com/maxdesign/basicdesign/principles/prinlayout.html

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstand the issue (from reading possibly some outdated material on the internet).

Tables are useful for displaying tabular data, so it makes sense to use them for such purpose.

Sure, your main layout will be using `<div>` tags but you have to use every tool in the toolbox to design a great website that is easy to maintain. You can't just say, well I am only going to use `<div>` and `<span>`. You will use appropriate elements to do the job they are designed to do. Tables for tabular data, divs for layout, spans to display snippets of text, anchors for links, ul tags for lists, etc.

Answer (score 1):

A few resources, off the top of my head:

- [960.gs - 960px grid](https://960.gs/)
- [cssgrid.net - 1140px grid by Andy Taylor](https://web.archive.org/web/20111201092253/http://cssgrid.net/)
- [Rethinking css grids - Mark Boulton](https://web.archive.org/web/20120414110835/http://www.markboulton.co.uk/journal/comments/rethinking-css-grids)
- [Relevance of the baseline grid - Elliot Jay Stocks](https://elliotjaystocks.com/blog/the-relevance-of-the-baseline-grid/)
- [Page Layouts, best practices in web design](http://www.iraqtimeline.com/maxdesign/basicdesign/principles/prinlayout.html)
- [css layouts - MaxDesign](https://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/css-layouts/)
- [Modern css layouts, essential techniques - Smashing Magazine](https://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/05/06/modern-css-layouts-part-2-the-essential-techniques/)

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend you this [float tutorial](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/floatutorial/) or any other tutorial you can find on http://css.maxdesign.com.au/.

Answer (score -2):

Changing a Photoshop PSD to HTML (DIV's)

I think this is what you mean, it is a tutorial how to make HTML 2.0 out of a PSD: http://www.bolducpress.com/tutorials/from-photoshop-to-html/

Comment: What is HTML 2.0? I thought the current debate was HTML 4.01 vs. XHTML 1.0 vs. HTML 5?

Comment: My understanding of this question is how to change from tables to divs. Maybe I read it wrong, or it was not a really clear question.

Comment: Think higher level.  What is the user trying to do.  Basically layout without tables.  The user has indicated they are a newbie so better to give advice on the right way to do it.  Why teach bad technique?